# bad argument type for built-in operation Numba

Tags: python, numba

I'm tryng to use the @vectorize numba decorator and I'm getting this error. In a code like this one

Code:

```
@vectorize([int32(int32),
            int64(int64),
            float32(float32),
            float64(float64)])
def barrido(frec):

    return np.array([1,1])
```

Error:

When I put

```
frec=np.arange(0,1,0.1)
E=barrido(frec)
```

I get this

```
 File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/USUARIO...", line 174, in <module>
    E=barrido(frec)

TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

Someone knows what is happening?

Comment: Because an array is not an int or a float? Why do you expect `np.arange(0,1,0.1)` to return something other than an array?

Comment: Or that an array argument would have mixed precision

Comment: the same happens when I put float64([1,1]) as input